# Character Building

Tags: discussion

I just created a new [proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119739/character-building?referrer=_s82BQxUQczWn9bHNgPGRw2) on Area 51 after discussion with the Worldbuilding gang. However, when I shared it with the literature site in the chat (along with the Sci Fi and this site), I was tipped that it might overlap in scope with this site. Is that so, or are the scopes different enough that I should leave it up?

Comment: Sadly, this proposal's been closed as it's believed to be a subsection of `Writing`

Comment: However, I'm proposing a site - 'Writing Review' - where critiques and reviews and feedback on texts and passages can be provided ---> https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119758/writing-review?referrer=GKuUTdJCQgHeVZXujr9WCA2

Comment: Area51 is unlikley to provide a way forward on this: https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1643/24040

Answer (score 2):

I think your proposal was too specific. What we need is a brainstorming site. Somewhere where you can finally ask "What to write"

This would be similar to world building but would let us ask about ideas for characters and settings. Your Character Building idea could be a type of question being asked there.

I see a need for this kind of site on WoldBuilding and Writers every day

Comment: While I have to agree that a brainstorming site would be useful I don't think that the Stack Exchange model works for the process.

Comment: @Ash we have a very healthy code gold site where everyone tries to write the most fun answer to a programming question. There are no right answers on code golf, and many questions get 20+answers, but it works

Comment: Okay maybe as a specific and dedicated space but it would be a pretty exceptional space within the network.